# Rendering nested objects in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte-3

the JSON file looks like below. You can find the entire JSON file at https://api.mocki.io/v1/0f83a2e7

```
  {
          "rows": [
            {
              "key": [
                "0x1d42",
                {
                  "x": 10.32,
                  "y": 11.13,
                  "z": 1.22
                }
              ],
              "value": {
                "pos": {
                  "x": 10.32,
                  "y": 11.13,
                  "z": 1.22
                },
                "id16": "0x1d42",
                "resultTime": "2021-02-21T23:28:03.558Z"
              }
            },
           .......
        ]}
```

I want to extract values.pos, values. id16, values.resultime.
I tried the below code but it is not giving me any results.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    const apiURL = "https://api.mocki.io/v1/0f83a2e7";
    let data = [];
     onMount(async function() {
        const response = await fetch(apiURL);
        data = await response.json();
    });
</script>

<pre>
<div>
{#each data.rows as row }
                        <div>
                        {#each row.value as value}
                <p> {value.pos} </p>
                        {/each}
            </div>                      
 {/each}
</div>  
</pre>
```

How can I extract these values so that I can display them in the table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to remark is that in Svelte `onMount` is executed **after** the markup has been rendered for the first time (during the`onMount` it can of course be updated) this means that the initial state of your component has to be able to render without a problem, which it doesn't.

You try to iterate over `data.rows` but this property does not exist initially, you could solve this by initializing data with a property rows: `let data = { rows: [] }`

Then you try to iterate over `value`, but value is not an array, so it will not be able to loop over it.

Also `value.pos` would be an object (x,y,z) so when it eventually renders it will just show `[Object object]` in the output.

You would extract these values simply by pointing directly at them: `<p>{row.value.pos.x}</p>`

(It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do here.)

That said, you can make the code a lot simpler by using the [await block](https://svelte.dev/docs#await)

```html
<script>
  const apiURL = "https://api.mocki.io/v1/0f83a2e7";
  const load = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
</script>

{#await load(apiURL) then data}
  <pre>
    <div>
      {#each data.rows as row }
        <div>
          <p>{row.value.pos.x}</p>
          <p>{row.value.pos.y}</p>
          <p>{row.value.pos.z}</p>
        </div>                      
      {/each}
    </div>  
  </pre>
{/await}
```

with this code you wait with rendering until you get your response back and you know that `data` will always have the correct format

Comment: I just have one more question. How can put these {row.value.pos.x}
  {row.value.pos.y} values into a array. I wan array[{x:row.value.pos.x},{y:row.value.pos.y}]something like this.